# Not able to generate SAS in Azure APIM using Microsoft sample

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-sas

Has anyone succeeded to generate a SAS for the Blob Storage in Azure APIM following the sample below?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/generate-shared-access-signature

Have substituted the storage access keys from the portal (used key1 and key 2), but got the same results. Also tried to generate the new key, but it did not work either.

> "Expression evaluation failed. The given key was not present in the
> dictionary.\r\n   at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)",
> "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

What added more confusion to azure-apim starter like me is
`<set-variable name="resourcePath" value="TableName()" />`, what does TableName() do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all who have tried to help: Anton and Doris.

Operation that was failing was this block:

```
<set-variable name="StringToSign" value="@{
            return string.Format(
            "GET\n\n\n\n\n{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}",
            (string)context.Variables["Content-Type"],
            (string)context.Variables["x-ms-date"],
            (string)context.Variables["x-ms-version"],
            (string)context.Variables["CanonicalizedResource"]);
        }" />
```

But, in the beginning of the sample, when context variables were set, x-ms-version was missing. I added operation `<set-variable name="x-ms-version" value="2020-02-10" />` and SAS is now being generated.

Maybe it will help someone else who wants to use azure :)

Comment: so the `TableName()` its really works and its some undocumented build in function? (APIM specific)

Comment: Sorry @max3d ,I search everywhere, but didn't find a description about the `TableName()` function.  Could you  update how you set "resourcePath" variable and accept your answer for others to refer?

Comment: It feels like TableName() is just a typo - I did not see it being evaluated as expression or call.

I have replaced it with containername, as Doris suggested:

`<set-variable name="resourcePath" value="containername" />`

And in the rewrite-uri, was referring to that variable:

`<rewrite-uri template="@{return (string)context.Variables["resourcePath"];}" />`

As a result, the call to the backend was correctly formed:
https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/containername

The signature is not valid though, but is being generated. That needs a bit more investigation

Answer (score 0):

This sample generates SAS token for a table in Azure Storage account. You could modify it to the resources you want to access, like this:

```
<set-variable name="resourcePath" value="containername/blobname" />
```

Don't forget to change the `rewrite-uri` block, too.

Comment: Did you know what is `TableName()`? If API management save policy with this code it look like `TableName()` some build-in function.. idk

Comment: Thanks for replies. Yes, I have been attempting to use it for Blob. Should the value of the containername be as you described - container name only, or also include the top-level domain (.blob.core.windows.net)? Anyway, I will retry with your example Doris Lv, and update the post